# Discuss the following relation s about upper and lower Riemann sums

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

> Let , $f$ be a continuously differentiable real-valued function on $[a,b]$ such that $|f'(x)|\le k $ for all $x\in [a,b]$. For a partition $P=\{a=a_0<a_1<a_2<\cdots <a_n=b\}$ let $U(P,f)$ and $L(P,f)$ denotes the upper and lower Riemann sums of $f$ with respect to $P$. Then ,
>
> (A) $|L(P,f)|\le k(b-a)\le|U(P,f)|$
>
> (B) $U(P,f)-L(P,f)\le k(b-a)$
>
> (C) $U(P,f)-L(P,f)\le k||P||$ , where $||P||=\max_{0\le i\le n-1}(a_{i+1}-a_i)$
>
> (D) $U(P,f)-L(P,f)\le k||P||(b-a)$

I really can't understand how I utilize the condition $|f'(x)|\le k$ ?

Can anyone give me any hint ?

Comment: At first glance, maybe you should try to use the Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, for all $x,y \in [a,b]$, 
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq k(x-y)$$
Let $x_{M_i}$ and $x_{m_i}$ denote the $x$-coordinates of the maximum and minimum of the function in each subinterval. Then
\begin{align*}
U(P,f) - L(P,f) &= \sum_{i=0}^n (M_i - m_i) \Delta x_i \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \left(f(x_{M_i}) - f(x_{m_i})\right) \Delta x_i \\
&\leq \sum_{i=0}^n k(x_{M_i} - x_{m_i}) \Delta x_i \\
&\leq k ||P|| \sum_{i=0}^n \Delta x_i \\
&= k ||P|| (b-a).
\end{align*}